# SlickJS Video Carousel Pause YouTube Video, And Hide Placeholder Image Permanently

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, carousel, slick.js

Here's the CodePen: http://codepen.io/frankDraws/pen/RWgBBw

Summary
This is an ad with a video carousel, using SlickJS.

There are only 3 YouTube videos, but Slick has an `infinite` option which we're using.

Problem
1. I need the placeholder `img` to hide permanently on click (including the clones).
2. I need the YouTube video to pause on scroll prev/next (including the clones).
3. I would love to consolidate the final code for this as well.

Currently the placeholder disappears on click, but when you scroll, it reappears (depending on which placeholder you click and which direction you scroll).

My guess is that somewhere in SlickJS, it's placing the image back. I don't know where in Slick it's doing this, nor do I know how to overwrite it.

I've been trying several ways, including:

```
$("#c1").on('click',function(){
  $(this).html('<iframe id="video01" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/c07DH4HY2CA?list=&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="width:305px; outline: 5px solid #fff; background:#000; margin:0 0 0 4px; padding:0"></iframe>');
  $("#c1 > img").hide();
});

$("#c2").on('click',function(){
  $(this).html('<iframe id="video01" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1bdtSFxBYW0?list=&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="width:305px; outline: 5px solid #fff; background:#000; margin:0 0 0 4px; padding:0"></iframe>');
  $("#c2 > img").hide();
});

$("#c3").on('click',function(){
  $(this).html('<iframe id="video01" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Js_Jv5EzOv0?list=&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="width:305px; outline: 5px solid #fff; background:#000; margin:0 0 0 4px; padding:0"></iframe>');
  $("#c3 > img").hide();
});
```

and `$("#c3 > img").style.display = "none";` just to hame a couple, but nothing has worked.

I appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick Code Pen that shows some useage of the YouTube IFrame API to control starting/pausing of videos:  http://codepen.io/ccaspanello/pen/RWZqXb

```
var currentPlayer;

$('#c1').on('click',function(){
    var player = new YT.Player('c1', {
        width: '305',
        videoId: 'c07DH4HY2CA',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
    currentPlayer = player;
});

// Other Videos Here

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event){
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        currentPlayer = event.target;
    }
}
```

Please note, that the onclick actions to generate videos can be consolidated into functions.  I did not take the time to do so.  If you need help doing that I can help out; but I probably won't be able to help out until later tonight.

In regards to the previews mysteriously coming back.  It look looks like SlickJS is cloning the contents so it can "loop" them once the user hits the end of the carousel.  After the user clicks a preview to generate the YouTube video; you may need to trigger an event to refresh the cloned objects.

Comment: This is awesome. It took me some time to figure out that I needed to use the YouTube API. I didn't need it for the last project but this one's different. I'm not always looking for a solves. Usually I just need to get unstuck. I can't tell you how much I appreciate this.

Comment: Anytime dude.  Always happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Cool problem to solve.  I've never played with SlickJS, but from what I'm reading is it doesn't do anything with video controls.  For that I would suggest looking at the YouTube IFrame API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).  You can call the `player.pauseVideo()` function to pause the video when you click the next/previous buttons.  This will also clean up the HTML replacement in your JS.

I'm close to a solution; but my battery is dying (%).  I'll try and finish tomorrow morning.